# Cómo agregar mas datos a un JSON usando javascript

Tags: javascript, json

tengo un archivo JSON con esta estructura:

```
{
   "[IDIOMA_ID]": "ES",
   "[IDIOMA]": "Español",
   "[NUEVO]": "¡Nuevo!"
}
```

El cual almaceno y leo perfectamente en una variable,

```
 let jSonFile = "/core/lang/" + langId + ".json";
 let jSonLang = JSON.stringify($BCL.loadJsonFile(jSonFile));
 localStorage.setItem("jsonDiccionary", jSonLang);
 var $GlobalJsonDiccionary = {};
 $GlobalJsonDiccionary = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jsonDiccionary"));
```

pero deseo en tiempo de ejecucion poder agregarla mas elementos a los datos que previamente fueron agregados en la variable ($GlobalJsonDiccionary) agregarle datos a la variable, no al archivo .JSON

Gracias

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué datos? ¿De dónde vienen esos datos? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el spread operator para agragar mas claves/valor a tu objeto:

```js
let jSonLang = {
   "[IDIOMA_ID]": "ES",
   "[IDIOMA]": "Español",
   "[NUEVO]": "¡Nuevo!"
  }
  console.log(jSonLang);

  jSonLang = { ...jSonLang, "agregado": "Algo mas" }

  console.log(jSonLang);
```

No se desde donde lo quieres agregar, si por ejemplo es desde un input con el name="nvoDato", puedes hacer dentro de un listener :

```js
let jSonLang = {
   "[IDIOMA_ID]": "ES",
   "[IDIOMA]": "Español",
   "[NUEVO]": "¡Nuevo!"
  }
  console.log(jSonLang);

  jSonLang = { ...jSonLang, "otroDato": "Algo mas" }

  console.log(jSonLang);
  
  document.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
   jSonLang = { ...jSonLang, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
   console.log(jSonLang);
  })
```

```html
<label for="">Ingresa nuevo dato<input type="text" name="nvoDato"></label>
```

Comment: Excelente respuetas, muchas gracias.